# I can't authenticate to remote host with password using 2FA

Tags: ssh, 20.04

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VM running as a jump box for the rest of my servers. I have connected it with a DDNS service to access it remotely. If I use ssh keys I can log in to the server normally, but if I use password authentication with 2FA (Google's pam 2fa module) I get "Authentication failed",

What can I do in order to fix that problem?

I have tried from different computers and OSes but the problem is from the machine itself. Google doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will not be installed per default in an Ubuntu and you will have to apply the configuration following this guide. Reference: [Ubuntu - Configure SSH 2FA](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/configure-ssh-2fa#1-overview) Pay attention to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in your Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, at the /etc/pam.d.sshd i had set the `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so` with the extra option `nullok`, after removing this I was able to ssh to the machine using the password and the 2fa generated codes.